# Visual Studio 2017 2 users on one desktop

Tags: build, proxy, visual-studio-2017, publish

I have the following problem: I have a Laptop with two different user accounts (UserA & UserB / they belong to the same person but have different priveleges).

UserA: can build the solution and run tests locally (Everything is working as expected)

UserB: Has the rights to publish to the specific network drive, however he cannot build the project. The reason is that the Windows user itself has not the correct proxy settings configured, and thats why the nuget packages cannot be downloaded.
I have no possibility to change the proxy settings for UserB right now (It depends on internal processes, which might take a while)

However I would have expected, that when I build the solution with UserA, UserB would not need to build it again and just can publish it. This, does not work, as soon as I want to publish, VS tries to rebuild the solution and this does not work because some dependencies are missing and cannot be loaded.

Is there any solution for this problem? I tried to make a research, however I was not really sure for the correct keywords to search for.

**Edit:** I have now the domain added to my UserB, but I still have some other problems. However I found out that this article is heavily related to my issue: [Unable to launch Visual Studio 2015 as a different user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39470842/unable-to-launch-visual-studio-2015-as-a-different-user).
When I start Visual Studio via Command Line with the mentioned arguments, more works, however I am now not able any longer to connect to my database using Integrated Security = true in the connection string. But at least I can build now. Deploying also works but I just get a 500 Server error when I try to connect to the resource.

**Edit2:** I needed to add the domain to my user when opening Visual Studio with the command mentioned in the link above. This fixed my problem with connecting to the database.
Actually I do not need an answer anymore for my initial question but I will not delete it because maybe someone has an answer for a person who will have the same question later on.